# dnx exec format error

Tags: .net, linux, bash

I was trying to install .NET core on my Arch Linux system. I followed this simple tutorial: http://dotnet.github.io/core/getting-started/
But when I try to execute the command dnx run, I get the following output:

```
bash: /home/karel/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-coreclr-linux-x64.1.0.0-rc1-15779/bin/dnx: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Can somebody help with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have mono package installed?

```
pacman -Qs mono
```

Comment: Yes, I do. I followed the tutorial I mentioned.

Comment: I got that error when, mono was not isntalled, and it clearly says that cannot find it. Please try `pacman -S mono` and let me know if it helped you.

Comment: look at the end of the error message: Exec format error. that clearly doesn't say anything. I am 100% sure I have mono installed. when I try pacman -S mono, the first line of the output is: warning: mono-4.0.4.1-1 is up to date -- reinstalling

Comment: That's strange. I had the same error. Hmm. Did you load dnvm.sh? `source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh`